# Get option name or other attribute with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's imagine this `<select>` element

```
<select name='chapter'>
    <option value='Select1' name='1'>Select1</option>
    <option value='Select2' name='2'>Select2</option>
    <option value='Select3' name='3'>Select3</option>
    <option value='Select4' name='4'>Select4</option>
    <option value='Select5' name='5'>Select5</option>
</select>
```

Using codeigniter with this line I would get the **value**

```
$this->input->post("chapter");
```

But how could I get the **name** or any other attribute? is it possible?

Comment: Any other other attribute means? With this `$this->input->post("chapter");` we can get the values for all input, text, select, textarea in the CodeIgniter and for files we can directly use $_FILES.

Comment: hi, if you want to get more elements in your select[name=chapter], you need to use js or send it separated with some character like <option vlaue="Select1|1" name="1"> ans in your controller make a exploit

Comment: Any other other attribute means? With this `$this->input->post("chapter");` we can get the values for all input, text, select, textarea in the CodeIgniter and for files we can directly use $_FILES.

Comment: With any other attribute I mean for example  `<option value='Select1' name='1' data-cost='15'>Select1</option>`. Get the attribute **data-cost**

Comment: @HectorLandete for this you need to use jQuery.

Comment: Can I use jquery in the controller? (sorry, I'm a frontend guy but I have to deal with it, have almost no idea about model-controller)

Comment: @elddenmedio didn't read that, is exactly what I was thinking if I can not do that. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using this method. According to codeigniter documentation you give as parameter the "name" and the return is the "value". You can have a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: ok, so I will pass all the data I want to use on the server side within the **value** and I'll split the string